# Ubuntu 18 Login Page - Text Size enlarged & Login-box move the location automatically

Tags: login, password

My little kids touched my laptop (touch screen), and make my ubuntu login page very weird.

The login page is still working. But the way it display is strange.
1) The User name /Password Box is getting very big (5 times as usual).Probablly out of the screen.
2) If I try to use the cursor to find the password textbox, the whole box moved automatically anywhere.

I still could type in the password to complete login. But want to fix this problem.

This situation happens only when the laptop newly restarted. Once start and login, if it turns to screen saver mode, and if i tried to relogin, everything works fine.

Anyone know how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Zoom feature.

On the login screen, go to the accessibility menu. That is, click on the little man with outstretched arms. You probably have "Zoom" enabled. Turn off Zoom and everything else that you don't specifically need.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, you are right. Acutually because it got zoomed so much, made it difficult to find this "Outstretched Arms", because it is out of the screen.

Comment: Good! If you are satisfied with my post, please mark the question as "answered" by ticking the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is my first post here. Never know I would get answer so fast ... Amazing